# php calculator displaying code in webrowser

Tags: php, oop, calculator

I have been working on a OOP calculator in php however I have a problem: whenever I save it and run it in firefox it shows the code like this

[image]

Stack overflow wants me to add some more description so blah blah blah blah

The code I have been using is

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$page = $GET['page'];

class calc{
    var $number1;
    var $number2;

        function add($number,$number2)
        {
            $result = $number1 + $number2;
            echo("The sum of $number1 and $number2 is $result<br><br>");
            echo("$number1 + $number 2 = $result");
            exit;
            }

        function subtract($number1,$number2)
        {
            $result = $number1 - $number2;
            echo("$number1 subtract $number2 is $result<br><br>");
            echo("$number1 - $number2 = $result");
            exit;
            }

        function multiply($number1,$number2)
        {
            $result  = $number1 * $number2;
            echo("$number1 multiplied by $number2 is $result<br><br>");
            echo("$number1 * $number2 = $result");
            exit;
            }

        function divide($number1,$number2)
        {
            $result = $number1 / $number2;
            echo("$number1 divided by $number2 is $result<br><br>");
            echo("$number1 / $number2 = $result");
            exit;
            }
            }
            $calc = new calc();
            ?>

<title>php object oriented calculator</title>
<form name="calc" action="?page=calc" method="POST">
Number 1: <input type=text name=value1><br>
Number 2: <input type=text name=value2><br>
Operation: <input type=radio name=oper value="add">Addition <input type=radio name=oper value="subtract">Subtraction <input type=radio name=oper value="divide">Division <input type=radio name=oper value="multiply">Multiplication</input><br>
<input type=submit value="Calculate">
</form> 

<?php
if($page == "calc"){
$number1 = $_POST['value1'];
$number2 = $_POST['value2'];
$oper = $_POST['oper'];
    if(!$number1){
        echo("You must enter number 1!");
        exit;
        }
        if(!$number2){
            echo("You must enter number 2!");
            exit;
            }
        if(!$oper){
            echo("You must select an operation to do with the numbers!");
            exit;
            }
        if(!eregi("0-9", $number1)){
            echo("Number 1 MUST be numbers!");
            exit;
            }
        if(!eregi("0-9", $number2)){
            echo("Number 2 MUST be numbers!");
            exit;
            }   
        if($oper == "add"){
            $calc->add($number1,$number2);
            }

        if $oper =="subtract"){
            $calc->subtract($number1,$number2);
            }
        if $oper = "multiply"){
            $calc->multiply($number1,$number2);
            }
        if $oper = "divide"){
            $calc->divide($number1,$number2);
            }
            }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paste the relevant code here, not in pastebin.

Comment: Put the code into the tags!

Comment: you don't have a starting <?php tag in the code and also ending ?> tag on the last line of the code.

Comment: @Maximus2012 There's one in the middle of the file

Comment: @Paarth: one isn't enough ;)

Comment: sorry forgot to add the <?php ?> tag in my code that i put here but i did on the real thing and it still dosent work

Comment: @AmalMurali Max's message was different when I posted that :P

Comment: The requested url starts with `file:///...` in the image. You should run your code in server(eg. WAMP, MAMP) in order to run php. You are also missing opening php tag `<?php`.

Comment: cant i run php straight from my computer

Comment: If you want to see it in a browser you have to run it on a webserver. WAMP is a good option for you to install a webserver on your computer.

Comment: @user2611495 You cannot run php straight from your computer like a html file. You need a web server to process your PHP script.

Comment: and there are some issues with the code as well. I made changes to your code to resolve some of those issues. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply run PHP by opening the file in the browser. Right now you're loading the file directly -- `file:///C:/Documents...`. That won't work. You'll need WAMP, XAMPP or a similar program (or download and install Apache, PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin etc. manually) to be able to run PHP.

- [Install XAMPP](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-XAMPP-for-Windows)
- [Install WAMP](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-WAMP)

Once it's installed, you can put the script file in `www` / `htdocs` folder and then load up `localhost/yourFile.php`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your browser does not know how to interpret PHP. You need to install PHP on your machine to interpret PHP and pass its results to your browser via a server.

As anon suggested, XAMPP and WAMP are good integrated solutions that installs the whole stack of technologies required.

Answer (score 0):

I made some debugging changes to your code. Try it here:

Code: http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/g9x-m73

Execute it: http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/g9x-m73

The code is not running for some reason in php fiddle but you can try it on your system.

Answer (score 0):

1. You missed the opening php tag `<?php`
2. Run your code in server. You are running your php code like a plain html file. [This tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-windows-web-server-pc-xampp/) will help you to install server in windows.